# How can a FileInputStream get the content of File?

Tags: java, file, fileinputstream

I have a file `f` and I need to affect it into a `FileInputStream` `fs` :

```
File f = new File("C:/dir/foo.txt");
FileInputStream fs = (FileInputStream)f;
```

But i get this error :

```
Cannot cast from File to FileInputStream
```

How can `fs` get the content of `f`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The trick is this:

```
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(f);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this approach:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("text.txt")))));

    String line = null;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // do something with your read line
    }
```

or this one:

```
    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("text.txt"));
    String text = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I found the solution :

http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/io/filestreams.html