# Reading and modifying an HTML file in Java

Tags: java, html, arrays, string, file

I have one HTML file and what I have to do is to store this file into some array or big string and then do the required modifications. I have to include some Javascripts and some other elements with attributes and also have to eliminate some of them. Can anyone plaese help me out in doing this. Thanking you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;  charset=utf-8" />  
<title>eXe</title>  
<style type="text/css">  
@import url(base.css);  
@import url(content.css);  
</style>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="common.js"></script>
<!--HERE I NEED TO INCLUDE 3 MORE JAVASCRIPTS-->  
</head>  
<body>  
<div id="outer">  
<div id="main">  
<div id="nodeDecoration">  
<p id="nodeTitle">  
Part 1</p>  
</div>  
<div class="TrueFalseIdevice" id="id12">  
<script type="text/javascript" src="common.js"></script>  
<!--THIS JAVASCRIPT HAS TO BE ELIMINATED-->  
<script type="text/javascript" src="libot_drag.js"></script>  
<div class="iDevice emphasis1">  
<img alt="" class="iDevice_icon" src="icon_question.gif" />  
<span class="iDeviceTitle">True-False Question</span><br/>  
<div class="iDevice_inner">  
<div id="ta12_16" class="block" style="display:block">  

</div><div class="question">  
<br/><br/><div id="taquestion0b12" class="block" style="display:block">1><span style="color: #000000; font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: normal; orphans: 2; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; display: inline ! important; float: none"> SQL Stands for Structure Query Language?</span>   

<!--THIS ONCLICK EVENT HAS TO BE REMOVED-->  
</div><br/>True <input type="radio" name="option0b12" id="true0b12" onclick="getFeedback(0,2,'0b12','truefalse')"/>   
False <input type="radio" name="option0b12" id="false0b12" onclick="getFeedback(1,2,'0b12','truefalse')"/>  
<div id="s0b0b12" style="color: rgb(0, 51, 204);display: none;" even_steven="18">Correct! </div>  
<div id="s1b0b12" style="color: rgb(0, 51, 204);display: none;" even_steven="19">Incorrect! </div>  
<div id="sfbk0b12" style="color: rgb(0, 51, 204);display: none;"><div id="tafeedback0b12" class="block" style="display:block">  
<!--HERE I NEED TO INCLUDE A SUBMIT BUTTON-->
</div></div>  
</div>  
</div>  
</div>  
</body></html>
```

Comment: @Genzer Hi, I have tried to read the file by using BufferedReader but I don't know how to add the required elements into it. I tried it by seeing this example-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563294/modifying-existing-file-content-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java already has a parser, called DOM that could help you. You could use something like this:

```
File theXML = new File("C:\\path\\to\\file.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(theXML);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

If you've ever used JavaScript DOM, you should know what to do now, use doc.getElementsByTagName or the like. If you don't, check out [the oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/index.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. I'll try in this way now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485311/how-can-a-fileinputstream-get-the-content-of-file/11485514#11485514) way to read your html (into a `String`). After that, your task is actualy to do some `String` splitting, replacing and inserting, and, finally, writing it all to the `html` file on your HDD using a simiar method as you read it from the HDD.